# Keyboard shortcut for searching object browser in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need to frequently search the object browser, so I need to find a way to speed up the process. There is a shortcut key to open object browser <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, but after the object browser is opened, I still need to use the mouse to move the focus to the search box. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> moves the focus around, but never to the search box.

Is there a built-in keyboard shortcut to search the object browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the middle of typing this question, I found a way to speed up searching in object browser. In visual studio options - environment - keyboard, there is an entry called `View.ObjectBrowserGoToSearchCombo`. I map this to a keyboard shortcut (for my case <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>). Now I can open object browser and move the focus to the search box by just pressing this shortcut key twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the search in Solution Explorer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>.  Solution Explorer will now drill down to show you methods and properties.

Comment: That's also what I use mostly (also with Ctrl-[-s to navigate to the current file in Solution Explorer), but in contrast to the Object Explorer that only works for files defined in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In English Visual Studio 2019 the default shortcut seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.